# "Integrily excelsior gratitude grethi sealiton” revisited

Tags: sentence-translation

[I post anew, since I can't comment or edit.]

The phrase

> Integrily excelsior gratitude grethi sealiton

can be found on a tattoo on the chest of an actor (he's a public person and the tattoo is clearly visible in television so I think I can post this) known from the popular Finnish telenovella "Salatut Elämät". Look at the picture for example here:

[image: the tattoo]

the picture is taken from: https://www.instagram.com/p/Bc2QzPTDs99/?taken-by=samiuotila

Comment: Should I delete the old question? You will be able to comment and edit, and you will be notified of any comments if you register your account. Unregistered accounts have limited functionality. (If you register your account, I can also merge the previous one to it.)

Answer (score 6):

It shouldn't be read as a phrase but as a series of noble sentiments:

- "Integrity"  - a virtue [English]
- "excelsior"  - "[ever] higher" (the only Latin word here, also the motto of New York) [Latin]
- "gratitude"  - a virtue [English]
- "gnothi seauton" - "know thyself" (the "gnothi" may be misspelt; it's a bit hard to tell) [Greek]

Comment: I would also venture to say that "Integrity" was misspelled seeing as there is no crossbar on the t, making it integrily.

Comment: It looks to me like a Greek nu (ν) instead of an "n." It must be some kind of confusion, though, since the rest is transliterated.

Comment: @brianpck. Could be, but it looks to me as though there's a mole or something that got in the tattoo artist's way; so he/she skipped over it and then resumed to ink in the bottom of the 'n' and the connector to the 'o'. I'd say there's an actual 'n' there.